# MYSQL select where field does not contain a certain string character

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic, sitemap

I use sql to select all my sites URLs from a table.

```
$sql = 'select * from pages where "myURL field";
```

However I want to be a little more specific with my query. There are a few duplicate links in my table for example:

```
about-us
./about-us
```

I don't want the `./about us` field to be selected. Is there a way of saying:

```
select * where "myURL field" does not begin with . /
```

Or should I just forget it and parse using PHP?

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE some_col NOT LIKE './%';
```

This will fetch all rows where some_col is not starting with `./`

Comment: Works a treat, nice one : )

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIKE` in mysql to check that it is not starting with `./`. Use the code below

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE col_name NOT LIKE './%';
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from pages where my_url NOT LIKE './%';
```